# Navbar Contents Missing On Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've read through similar issues, but those solutions didn't seem to resolve my problem. My navigation bar works perfectly in different browsers on my laptop, but not on my iPhone. The background color and the border show up, but none of the links do.

Here is a link to the site: www.salesianacademy.com

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!-- main navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="menu">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="pull-left"><a class="home" href="#">SALESIAN ACADEMY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#the-academy">The Academy</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="pull-right"><a href="#contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
    /* NAVIGATION MENU */

.navbar-default {
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

Thank you for your help. I can usually stumble across the answer on my own, after a few hours of Googling... but I just cannot figure this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the code for the nav toggle:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

See [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Without that, there's nothing to toggle the links on mobile--essentially leaving you with an empty navbar

Comment: That did it! Genius! Thank you. I don't have enough "points" to vote up, but I hope others will...